# Consuming REST Webservice. API Key Authentication

Tags: c#, web-services, rest

I have little problem that I have been trying to solve for some time. I want to connect to a REST web service and I have the API key for that web service that I want to consume. I have tried the service in the Google REST console and it works fine.

But when I try to build a c# .net project for it I dont know how to set the api key for the authentication. I took this code from other site:

```
string url = "http://Demo.company.com/Data/Values/1029/CarPart/id/"
HttpWebRequest GETRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
GETRequest.Method = "GET";

Console.WriteLine("Sending GET Request");
HttpWebResponse GETResponse = (HttpWebResponse)GETRequest.GetResponse();
Stream GETResponseStream = GETResponse.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(GETResponseStream);

Console.WriteLine("Response from Server");
Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadToEnd());
```

How can I authenticate this service with my Api key: asdf1234. I need to add it to my header but how? Can you show me some code example?

Cheers
Thor

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to do something like:

```
HttpWebRequest GETRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
GETRequest.Method = "GET";
GETRequest.Headers.Add("api-key", "asdf1234");
```

Where "api-key" is the name of the header you want to set.

Comment: Ok. Im just going to ask like a stupid. This header name, is that something unique that I get from the REST web service documenetation or is it just header name that is specified in the HttpWebRequest class? Where can I find the name of this header I want to set?

Comment: It should be in the REST service documentation. If you post a link to the REST documentation I can take a look.