# Android App: Return Json encoded data with PHP

Tags: php, android, json

I have this code at the end of a php file in my server:
"echo json_encode($response);"

and with Jparser  "read" the encoded data and appear them as a List View.
Anything works fine but  the encoded data appears to browser when someone  call this php file directly from browser.

I try without echo but  the list view does not appear in app. I try also " return json_encode($response);" but i have the first same problem with browser!!!

Is there any way to not print json encoded data  at browser  ? (and my listView works too?)

Thanks  !

Answer (score 0):

So you're effectively using the php on the webserver as a webservice endpoint, and the php file can be viewed by anyone using a browser.

Is the android app the only consumer of the JSON data?

It sounds like what you need is an "API Key" to restrict access. See [Consuming REST Webservice. API Key Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12755324/consuming-rest-webservice-api-key-authentication) . This will keep anyone who doesn't have the key from consuming the data from your service. If the PHP file doesn't see the api key in the header, then it doesn't return any data.

If this is very sensitive data, you'll need to look further than the example above and consider SSL.